# "Log in to Portal as user" button on contact is missing in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience

I want to migrate to lightning experience, and I don't see the "Log in to Portal as user" button in my lightning contact layout.

If I view the contact layout in classic Salesforce, I can see and manage the button:

[image: Existing external user buttons]

But on the lightning experience contact page I can see the "Enable Customer User" button only:

[image]

And this is on the same contact (my contact has already a user).

Am I doing something wrong?

Does anybody know if this feature is available today for lightning experience?

Comment: Any idea if this is available yet?

Comment: This is not available, I have created my own set of buttons to do that

Comment: @ItaiShmida, I'm about to embark on that same task.  Any chance you might be willing to share the implementation of those buttons? No problem if it would violate IP restrictions. Just figured I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: I'll try to create a gist project for you

Comment: please look at my answer and rate it, any comments for the gist would be highly appreciated

Comment: Update to the missing functionality: in the new upcoming Winter18 release, all these features should be available now in lightning: [https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** This has been available since the [Winter '18 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm)

This feature is currently unavailable in Lightning UX:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_gaps_limitations_other_products.htm

This was a big reason why I have not moved my Org to Lightning.

Comment: We've run into some issues with some of the gaps in lightning UX, hopefully they will address sooner than later

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this document says that Salesforce Communities is not supported. I don't need support in communities, I just need this button. And if this is the reason - why is the "Enable Customer User" button available?

Answer (score 4):

I am posting here my component for `Log in as a Portal User` and `Enable Customer User` buttons - for users to use until Salesforce creates standard buttons for that.

I have created a gist for that:

[PortalUser.cmp](https://gist.github.com/itaishmida/6c286a005efc26cf484043cb27927e7f)

This lightning component is a card box to add to your contact record page.

Inside this gist there is one lightning component bundle, and one apex class.

The card displays a button:

- If current contact has a portal user, the button is for login to the portal
- If current contact does not have a portal user the button is for creating a portal user

Comment: thanks for posting this. Is this free to use, even in a commercial application? If so, is there any type of license or statement of reuse you'd like to add to the gist to clarify that? Just always have to cover the bases when using code that wasn't produced in-house. Thanks again!

Comment: I posted it so everyone can make use of it - private commercial and all. So fill free to use. If you have any fixes or comments - please send me so I can update the post. Also - you can up-vote this answer as useful to say thanks.

Comment: all these features should be available now in lightning: [https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available after the Winter '18 release. Go Lightning!

Comment: Please add a link to the relevant release notes to back up this claim.